# connection to OLAP cube?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I made an OLAP cube in Microsoft BI and deployed it on server. Now I want to make a web app ( ASP.Net MVC) on which I woud like to display reports (dashboards)  from OLAP cube, but I dont know how to make a connection to OLAP cube? 
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference to Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient; (browse for C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\110) and then add using Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient;
example:

```
        var connection = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=localhost;Catalog=DB Name");

        var dataAdapter = new AdomdDataAdapter("MD QUERY", connection);

        DataSet ol_DataSet = new DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(ol_DataSet);

        GridView1.DataSource = ol_DataSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

(in view add GridView)

Comment: Guys check out [this proposal for a dedicated Business Intelligence Q&A site right under Stackechange umbrella. Throw all your sample BI questions there.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2)